# Openssl version within Apache

Tags: openssl

I have installed (long time ago) Apache server on Ubuntu 12.04.
How could I know the Openssl version my server is using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your terminal and type `openssl` after that a prompt will come up and just type in `version`. The OpenSSL version should print to the console.

Comment: but is not that the version of openssl installed on my computer and which has nothing to do with Apache 2 that has maybe an embedded independant openssl version

Comment: Did this answer work for you, then? Sorry; I was a bit confused with your question at first.

Comment: yes, thank you. You must be here instead of being on Facebook: at least here you can be useful for the humankind :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command,

```
apt-cache policy openssl
```

To get the installed openssl version only, then run the below command

```
apt-cache policy openssl | awk '/Installed:/ {print $2}'
```